# how to display a session value in an ASP textbox

Tags: asp.net, session, textbox

A basic question but there is no such question on Stack Overflow (for ASP.NET)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Text=<% Session["UserName"] %> >
```

I did this a week ago, now something is wrong. It should be simple. I also tried <%= %>, it did not work either. Putting a single quote around '<% %>' gives binding error. Help

Comment: solved it. Will post the solution when I am allowed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did was pulled the text box in C# code and set it text value to the session.
Example:

```
txtUserName.text = Session["UserName"];
```

Use it in one of the function which checks the session values or you can use in page_load function (the default function for every page)

Answer (score 8):

I normally hide the implementation details from the aspx code with a property:

.cs file

```
public string UserName { get { return Session["UserName"]; } }
```

.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Text='<%= UserName %>' >
```

Comment: word prefer something in .aspx :)

Comment: It's probably the same sintax in the aspx, maybe the quotes are causing you problems.

Comment: I would think this sintax '<%= does not work with server tag properties.

Comment: @Ernesto Yeah that might be wrong, I dont have a compiler in front of me right now. <%: or <%# might work better.

Answer (score 1):

Now I think your code should look like `<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Session["UserName"] %>' >`

I always forget the sintax for inline code, [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112) information could be helpfull I think.

Comment: this is syntax for binding, i think i tried that, didn't work

Comment: It does work but I forgot to add you need to call the databind method on the control for it to be evaluated. Yours is what I would normally do but you said to asawyer that you would preffer something in aspx.

Comment: Does that mean I have to bind the session to the textbox control in properties or  I have to invoke textbox.databind() function in order to bind. Seems too much work. Properties window did not allow to bind session variables for me.

Comment: Just call databind. Again, I think what you did is the normal way to do it.