# How to get a value from a session in ASP.NET 4.0 and store it to a textbox/ label

Tags: c#, .net, session, textbox

i must to a project for school ,i must build an asp.net (4) site
and i need to get a value from  a session variable and to store it in an textbox or label what ever. I've tried with textbox until now........and i got stuck.

My session variable declare on page Default.aspx:

```
Session["user"] = username;
```

My textbox code on Home.aspx page :

```
<div class="content"><!--D2-->
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="logged"><!--D3-->
        <p class="i_am">You are logged in as:<asp:TextBox ID="txt_loggedas"      runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LogOut">[Log Out]</asp:LinkButton>
```

I tried answers from this link: [how to display a session value in an ASP textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791030/how-to-display-a-session-value-in-an-asp-textbox),  but i didn't succeed x-(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On your Default.aspx.cs file, you can get the value of the session like this:

```
txt_loggedas.Text = Session["user"].ToString();
```

Comment: Ive managed to find the answer but I couldn't post it because is a limit time to post answers to ypur questions any way I switched to label and my code looks like this : protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["user"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else {
          lbl_logged.Text = (string)Session["user"].ToString();
        }
    }