# Using Code Blocks in asp:textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, codeblocks

I'm pulling two dates from a database using SQL and saving those values to the session variables "blackoutbegin" and "blackoutend". I'm either running into the error of "Code blocks are not supported in this context" or "the server tag is not well formed" when playing around with this code.

Any suggestions on how to incorporate these session variables into the text of an asp:TextBox?

Or alternate options?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" 
             multiline="true" 
             ID="txtIndex" 
             Height="75px" 
             MaxLength="2000" 
             Width="100%" 
             TextMode="MultiLine" 
             Text="(More text before this)is expected to begin on '<%# Session["blackoutbegin"] %>' and is expected to end the week of '<%# Session["blackoutend"] %>'."> 
</asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer will help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791030/how-to-display-a-session-value-in-an-asp-textbox)

or simple you can assign the `text` to the `textbox` in `pageLoad` event as follow:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtIndex.Text="(More text before this)is expected to begin on "+ Session["blackoutbegin"].ToString() +" and is expected to end the week of "+ Session["blackoutend"].ToString() +".";
}
```